# Covariance Operator corresponding to multivariate covariance function

Tags: functional-analysis, statistics, reference-request, stochastic-processes, covariance

The usual definition of a covariance operator on $L_2(D)$ is:

$$
C : L_2(D) \to L_2(D), \qquad (C \psi)(x) = \int_D c(x,y) \psi(y) dy \qquad \forall x\in D, ~~\psi \in L_2(D),
$$
where $c(x,y): D \times D \to \mathbb{R}$ is the corresponding covariance function. The operator norm is then
$$
\|C\|= \sup_{\|\psi\|_{L_2}=1} \sqrt{\int_D \left(\int_D c(x,y)\psi(y) dy\right)^2dx}
$$
I am interested in the covariance operator corresponding to a multivariate covariance function. For example in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.08017.pdf) the author describes the multivariate covariance function $K: D \times D \to \mathbb{R}^p \times \mathbb{R}^p$, so now we have a matrix valued covariance function $K(x,y) = [c_{ij} (x,y)]$ where $c_{ij}$ is a univariate covariance function defined as above.

My question is about the operator corresponding to $K$, and the definition of the operator norm. Is it correct to write this as:

$$
C_K: (L_2(D))^p \to (L_2(D))^p, \qquad 
(C_K \psi)(x) =\int_{D} (K(x,y))^T \psi(y) dy, \qquad \forall x \in D, ~~ \psi \in (L_2(D))^p
$$
and
$$
\|C_K\|= \sup_{\| \psi \|_{(L_2(D))^p}=1}
\sqrt{\int_{D} \left ( \int_{D} (K(x,y))^T\psi(y) dy \right )^2dx}
$$

I am also wondering if there are any good references that discuss this setting in more detail.

Comment: what is $D$? Can you be more specific?

Comment: $D$ is just an arbitrary set, say $D= [0,1]^d$ for $d \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: $\|C_K\|$ as you defined it doesn't make sense, since you're taking the supremum of something that is ultimately matrix-valued. Maybe you want to apply the Euclidean norm on the innermost integral and *then* square it?

Comment: Obscure. since $(c_{ij})$ is a matrix $p\times p$ and not an element of $R^p\times R^p.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are just trying to write out the general operator norm in this setting. (I would say that the choice of $p$ for the dimension is unfortunate, since it too much reminds $L_p(D)$. I will call it by $n$ from now on.)

In your univariate case, your concrete formula is just
$$
\|C\| = \sup_{\|\psi\|_{L_2(D)} = 1} \|C\psi\|_{L_2(D)}.
$$
Therefore in the multivariate case, the norm should be
$$
\|C_K\| = \sup_{\|\psi\|_{L_2(D)^n} = 1} \|C_K\psi\|_{L_2(D)^n}.
$$

So it all boils down to how you define your norm on $L_2(D)^n$.
The norm on $L_2(D)^n$ comes from $L_2(D)$, just like a norm on ${\mathbb R}^n$ comes from the absolute value norm $|\cdot|$ on ${\mathbb R}$. You can do $L^1, L^\infty$ or $L^2$, and they are all equivalent. So you can define the norm of $\psi = (\psi_1,\dots, \psi_n)\in L_2(D)^n$ as any of the following
\begin{gather*}
\sum_{i=1}^n \|\psi_i\|_{L_2(D)} = \sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{\int_D \psi_i^2(x)\,dx},\\
\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \|\psi_i\|^2_{L_2(D)}} = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \int_D \psi_i^2(x)\,dx},\\
\max_{1\leq i\leq n} \|\psi_i\|_{L_2(D)} = \max_{1\leq i\leq n} \sqrt{\int_D \psi_i^2(x)\,dx}.
\end{gather*}

So pick any of these, you have a version of $\|C_K\|$ defined. (Again, they are all equivalent norms.) Say for the $L^2$, i.e. Euclidean norm, we have concretely
\begin{align*}
\|C_K\| &= \sup_{\|\psi\|_{L_2(D)^n} = 1} \|C_K\psi\|_{L_2(D)^n}\\
&= \sup_{\sum_{i=1}^n \int_D \psi_i^2(x)\,dx = 1} \sqrt{ \sum_{i=1}^n \int_D \Big(\int_D \sum_{j=1}^n c_{ij}(x, y)\psi_j(y) \,dy\Big)^2 \,dx}.
\end{align*}

I think the relevant reading is product norm, but more importantly what type of function $c(x, y)$ would define such a map (not discussed in this question).

Comment: thanks - this makes sense, but i'm a bit confused about your last line. Could you explain what you mean by what type of function would define such a map ?

Comment: I only know this from the functional analysis point of view. There, such an $C: L_2(D)\to L_2(D)$ is defined if the kernel function $c(x, y)$ satisfies some properties. I imagine it is the same situation here, and we would have similar conditions on the matrix-valued $K(x, y)$. That is all I mean by the last sentence.